# jQuery selector is not working after modifying DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I have a list of selected companies which looks like this:

```
<div id="selected_companies">
    <div class="company">
      <a>
        <div class="delete_company"></div>
        Company One
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="company">
      <a>
        <div class="delete_company"></div>
        Company Two
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have "move" each `.company` div into a separate `#deleted_companies` div when one of the companies is clicked. I am doing this with jQuery:

```
$('#selected_companies .company a').on('click', function (e) {
        /* Getting the company */
        var company_id = $(this).prev().prop('value');
        $('.form').append('<input type="hidden" name="deleted_companies[]" value="'+ company_id +'" />');

        var parent = $(this).parent();

        parent.appendTo('#deleted_companies');
        $('#deleted_companies').slideDown(300);
});
```

When I click on one of the companies, the `.company` div moves into the desired div (`#deleted_companies`), but when I try to reach it within that div, it does not perform as expected. For example, this code does not work:

```
$('#deleted_companies .company a').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('This should work.');
});
```

So how do I make that alert work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use delegation, try this

```
$('#deleted_companies').on('click', '.company a', function (e) {
    alert('This should work.');
});
```

This is basically saying to look at the `#deleted_companies` (which exists at the time your bind is created) for `.company a` which doesn't necessarily have to exist before this bind is created for it to work.

Comment: More about [direct vs. delegated event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8110934/578288)

Comment: Genius! I have worked on this for hours now. I guess I just didn't know how to search for it. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome link, @RoryO'Kane, can't believe it was THIS simple. Thanks a bunch!